# Postfix rewrites my return-path header

Tags: postfix-mta, return-path

I have noticed that although I pass a custom return-path header in mails going through my postfix server, the header gets re-written. I would like to pass my own header or at least construct a header dynamically. This is cause I want to get bounced emails on a specific email address (hence I need to pass in the return-path).

Is this possible?

Comment: How are these messages getting to postfix? Via SMTP or submitted to the `sendmail` command?

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `message_drop_headers` to not include the `return-path`.

```
message_drop_headers = "bcc, content-length"
```

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#message_drop_headers

Comment: I tried this setting and restarted but still i see return-path on the message_drop_headers, any idea?

Comment: What does `postconf -n | grep "message_drop_headers"` return?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set envelope sender address?
[`-f`command line option for sendmail look alike provided by postfix]

Many MTAs copy envelope sender address into (overwritten) `Return-Path:` header.

Comment: Hello - I have an Envelope To header if that makes sense.

Comment: "Envelope sender" means email address used in "MAIL FROM:" command in SMTP session.

Comment: isn't this my normal FROM address? Which is obviously different than the return-path address

Comment: "Envelope sender" ('MAIL FROM:' in SMTP session) and "header sender" (`From:` header in email message) may be different.